# Counting array operations in a Shell sort used for Integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, shellsort

I am trying to count the number of array operations (assignments into/out of the array, and comparisons to array elements) that happens throughout my Shell sorting method that takes in an Integer array.

This is the code that my Shell sort is using

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void shellSort(T[] a) {
    int gap = a.length / 2;
    while (gap >= 1) {
        if (gap % 2 == 0) {
            ++gap;
        }
        for (int i = gap; i < a.length; ++i) {
            int p = i;
            numAsgn++;
            T temp = a[p];
            numComp++;
            while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
                numAsgn++;
                a[p] = a[p - gap];
                p -= gap;
            }
            numAsgn++;
            a[p] = temp;
        }
        if (tracing) {
            System.out.println("...gap=" + gap + ": " + Arrays.toString(a));
        }
        gap /= 2;
    }
}
```

This is the output I am expecting.

(Note: I am performing the same thing for other sorting methods but that's irrelevant to my question)

[image: This is the output I am expecting]

The output I am getting for my shell sort:

[image]

So from that, I concluded that I am missing to update the value of `numComp` somewhere but I can't figure out where that is in my code.
Any help is appreciated.

In addition I tried to change the counting to this way. but to no avail.

```
//numComp++;
            while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
                numComp++;
                numAsgn++;
                a[p] = a[p - gap];
                p -= gap;
            }
```

I don't understand how this is possible since the loop would update `numComp++` more than one time, but rather here the number is substantially lower.

[image]

Comment: Is the array sorted at the end?

Comment: @NiVeR yes it is. But I am just printing out the values that are updated throughout the loops of the method after its finished. I'm not even storing the sorted array in the end.

Comment: According to my calculations 25 is wrong, the correct answer should be 24.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? and are you able to show me how I can update my values correctly to get 24? My professor provided the sample output with the 25 in it. I might have to contact him if his numbers are wrong @NiVeR

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        numComp++; // comparing perhaps more than once but only counted as once here
        while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) { // this loop will result in multiple comparisons, is it not?
            numAsgn++;
            a[p] = a[p - gap];
            p -= gap;
        }
```

Since a direct solution is required, how about we recording the inner comparisons separately and then adding it up to the *total* comparison counter as follows:

```
        numComp++; // for the loop termination comparison;
        int innerComp = 0; // for the loop non-termination comparison;
        while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
            innerComp++;
            numAsgn++;
            a[p] = a[p - gap];
            p -= gap;
        }
        numComp += innerComp;
```

Comment: You are not providing a solution.

Comment: @Hearen I tried your solution and it gave 30 as the number of #COMP in the end. That's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.....
T temp = a[p];
numComp++;
boolean in = false;
while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
    if(in) numComp++;
    in = true;
    numAsgn++;
    a[p] = a[p - gap];
    p -= gap;
}
.....
```

the key is not to count **twice** the *outside* comparison.

And then the part:

```
if (gap % 2 == 0) {
    ++gap;
}
```

it seems wrong and not necessary here, just remove it.

Complete code is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void shellSort(T[] a) {
    int gap = a.length / 2;
    int numAsgn = 0, numComp = 0;
    while (gap >= 1) {
        for (int i = gap; i < a.length; ++i) {
            int p = i;
            numAsgn++;
            T temp = a[p];
            numComp++;
            boolean in = false;
            while (p >= gap && a[p - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
                if (in)
                    numComp++;
                in = true;
                numAsgn++;
                a[p] = a[p - gap];
                p -= gap;
            }
            numAsgn++;
            a[p] = temp;
        }
        gap /= 2;
    }
    System.out.println(numComp + "," + numAsgn);
}
```

Comment: The output came out to be 21. I thought you said it will be 24? @NiVeR

Comment: There is a mistake in your code also, check the update.

Comment: Still with that removed it comes out to be 22. And actually, it's not my code. it's my professor's

Comment: I will give you whole function now, that I wrote. I removed some print statements for shortness.

Comment: It gave me 24 for #COMP and 54 for #ASGN. That's not correct :(

Comment: I think that the professor is wrong. I took another version of shellSort from geeksForGeeks and gives the same results (24 54). Check it https://pastebin.com/7pfJbX9j.